# Fresh Install of ArcMap 10.4 Stalls on "Loading Document"

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, windows-7, arcgis-10.4

I have just installed the trial version of the ArcGIS for Desktop which contains ArcMap on my Windows 7 Pro 64-bit.

I haven't been able to launch ArcMap, ArcScene or ArcGlobe yet. As of ArcMap it loads that initial banner and then stalls on `Loading Document`, then after a minute closes.

I haven't ever installed or used ArcGIS. I have already tried:

1. Remove the ESRI folder from %APP_DATA%/Roaming
2. Remove the ESRI key from the Registry
3. Run as administrator

Don't know what is the problem and support won't answer if I don't buy the product.

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/45924

Comment: Posted an answer! Glad it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a [bug](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/45924) which results from an upgrade of Python, following the steps in the link should hopefully resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem due to what turned out to be a graphics driver issue. In my case, I was using a ThinkPad docking station for my second monitor, and was able to successfully run ArcMap after running the graphics manufacturer's driver cleaner and installing the latest version of the driver.

The downloads I used were the following:

DisplayLink Installation Cleaner (8.1.808)

> (As of 8/3/17, located at http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/file?d=64)

DisplayLink USB Graphics Software for Windows 8.2 M3

> (As of 8/3/17, located at http://www.displaylink.com/downloads)

Comment: What graphics manufacturer and model was that?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem after upgrading from 10.3.1 to 10.5.1. For me it was also a graphics adapter problem. In my case, somebody had installed both an NVIDIA display adapter/driver and an Intel graphics driver. I checked the Display adapter being used in the Device manager and saw that it was the Intel Graphics driver so I uninstalled the NVIDIA stuff and ArcMap successfully loaded.